# Expected response code 220 but got an empty response in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using mailgun with laravel 5.6 to send email but its return error( Expected response code 220 but got an empty response). The following is my all file settings.

**.env FILE**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME = postmaster@domainname 
MAIL_PASSWORD = password
MAILGUN_DOMAIN = domainname 
MAILGUN_SECRET = key
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**mail.php File**

```
<?php

return [

     'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],
    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],
    'sparkpost' => [
        'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
    ],
    'stripe' => [
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ],
];
```

**services.php File**

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => 'aakanskhi.cuminte@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Aakankshi Gupta'],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('postmaster@domain'),
    'password' => env('mailgun password'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

```
    public function testmail(){
       $user = User::findOrFail(8);
       Mail::send('emails.test',  ['user' => $user], function ($message) {
       $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');
       $message->to('aakankshi.cuminte@gmail.com')->subject('Your Reminder!');
     });
    }
```

When I run the code it gives me following error message:

**Swift_TransportException**
**Expected response code 220 but got an empty response**

How do I resolve this error message?

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run this code on the terminal:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: How this could work? How config:cache is related with whatever? It is only cache. I expected config:clear.

Comment: I believe `config:cache` also runs `config:clear`

Answer (score 0):

For Mailgun only you have to specify the following fields in `.env` file, that's it.

> MAIL_DRIVER=`mailgun`
>
> MAILGUN_DOMAIN=`XY.mailgun.org`
>
> MAILGUN_SECRET=`key-XYZ`